# Laravel: value appears in log but get "Attempt to read property on null" in web

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a Eloquent query between models but I'm not being able to delivery the value to my controller.

I don't know what is happening. In the log the value is showing, but the code are not getting it.

My Controller

```
   $processedMaterialOrders = ProcessedMaterialOrder::get();

        $sessionVariables = Session::all();

        // Log::channel('ecom')->info($processedMaterialOrders);

        $filteredProcessedMaterials = [];
        foreach ($processedMaterialOrders as $key => $processedMaterialOrder) {
            // Log::channel('ecom')->info($processedMaterialOrder);

            $sectorId = $processedMaterialOrder->process->sector->id;
            Log::channel('ecom')->info($sectorId);
```

My relationship

```
ProcessedMaterial
 public function process(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Process::class, 'process_id');
    }
}

Process

 public function sector(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Sector::class);
    }
```

Log is returning:

```
[2023-11-11 16:49:39] local.INFO: 5  
[2023-11-11 16:49:39] local.INFO: 2  
[2023-11-11 16:49:39] local.INFO: 1  
[2023-11-11 16:49:39] local.INFO: 1  
[2023-11-11 16:49:39] local.INFO: 2  
[2023-11-11 16:49:39] local.INFO: 5  
[2023-11-11 16:49:39] local.INFO: 5  
[2023-11-11 16:49:39] local.INFO: 2  
[2023-11-11 16:49:39] local.INFO: 1
```

That ids exists in the sectors table.

Error page
https://flareapp.io/share/q5Ywd0xP

Thanks!

I've tried to understand e change all my code but it is not working.

How something can be printed in the log but not in the page?

Comment: Im not sure If I understood your question correctly. Are you trying to return the data from the controller to a view and access the relations there?

Comment: In the view the writing to the log is in the line following the error line.
Have you tried with *tinker* to access to *sector* data using an *id* of *ProcessedMaterialOrder* that gives null?

Comment: you are doing this in a loop, so it is failing on one of the iterations

Answer (score 0):

I've solved. It was database problems. One of the loop itens had no process_id.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here are three steps you may consider to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Check Eager Loading:
   Ensure that the relationships are being loaded correctly. You can
   use eager loading to improve performance and ensure that the related
   models are loaded. Modify your query to:

```php
$processedMaterialOrders = ProcessedMaterialOrder::with('process.sector')->get();
```

This will load Process and Sector relationships at the time of querying ProcessedMaterialOrder, reducing the number of queries to the database.

2. Ensure that the relationships in your models are defined correctly. From
   what you've provided, they seem correct. However, double-check the
   **foreign keys** and relationships in your `Process` and `Sector` models.
3. You are already logging the `sectorId`, which seems to work as expected. If you need to debug further, consider logging the entire `$processedMaterialOrder` object to see all its loaded relationships and attributes:

```php
Log::channel('ecom')->info(print_r($processedMaterialOrder->toArray(), true));
```

Finally you may consider to add error handling to catch any potential issues. For example, you might want to check if `$processedMaterialOrder->process` or `$processedMaterialOrder->process->sector` is `null` before trying to access the id.

```php
try {
    $processedMaterialOrders = ProcessedMaterialOrder::with('process.sector')->get();

    $filteredProcessedMaterials = [];
    foreach ($processedMaterialOrders as $processedMaterialOrder) {
        // Assuming that 'process' and 'sector' relationships might be null
        if ($processedMaterialOrder->process && $processedMaterialOrder->process->sector) {
            $sectorId = $processedMaterialOrder->process->sector->id;
            Log::channel('ecom')->info($sectorId);

            // Add your logic here to use $sectorId
        } else {
            // Handle cases where process or sector is not available
            Log::channel('ecom')->info('Process or Sector not found for ProcessedMaterialOrder ID: ' . $processedMaterialOrder->id);
        }
    }

    // Continue with your code, e.g., passing data to a view
    // return view('your_view', compact('processedMaterialOrders'));

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Handle exception
    Log::channel('ecom')->error("An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage());
    // Optionally, you can return an error response or view
    // return response()->json(['error' => 'An error occurred'], 500);
}
```